# coefficients of the linear model $y=β_0+β_1x_1+β_2x_2$ that minimises the sum of squares error

Tags: regression, linear-regression, data-analysis, logistic-regression, data-mining

Consider the following sample:
$$(x_{11}, x_{12}, y_1) = (1, 3, 4), $$$$(x_{21}, x_{22}, y_2) = (2, 1, 5),$$$$ (x_{31}, x_{32}, y_3) = (3, 0, 7),$$$$ (x_{41}, x_{42}, y_4) = (4, −2, 6).$$

How can I find the coefficients of the linear model $y = β_0 + β_1x_1 + β_2x_2$ that minimises the sum of squares error using normal equations. Justifying that this solution is unique.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is defined by the formula:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{array}{c}
\beta_0 \\ \beta_1 \\ \beta_2
\end{array}
\end{pmatrix} = \left(\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{Y},
$$

where

$$
\mathbf{Y} = \begin{pmatrix}
\begin{array}{c}
y_1 \\ y_2 \\ y_3 \\ y_4
\end{array}
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{array}{c}
4 \\ 5 \\ 7 \\ 6
\end{array}
\end{pmatrix} \text{ and }
\mathbf{X} = \begin{pmatrix}
\begin{array}{c}
1 & x_{11} & x_{12} \\ 
1 & x_{21} & x_{22} \\ 
1 & x_{31} & x_{32} \\ 
1 & x_{41} & x_{42} 
\end{array}
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{array}{r}
1 & 1 & 3 \\ 
1 & 2 & 1 \\ 
1 & 3 & 0 \\ 
1 & 4 & -2
\end{array}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

$\mathbf{X}^T$ is a *transpose matrix* of the matrix $\mathbf{X}$, and $\left(\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}\right)^{-1}$ is an *inverse matrix* of the matrix product of $\mathbf{X}^T$ and $\mathbf{X}$.